# Rails3 joins not including joined columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got two related `ActiveObject` models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product_type

 #contains a field called name
end

class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  # contains a field called name
end
```

If I join both models using their relationship, it all works well:

```
Product.joins(:product_type)
```

> "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" INNER JOIN \"product_types\" ON \"product_types\".\"id\" = \"products\".\"product_type_id\""

But now I need to get the Products that have an specific `ProductType`, and what I know is the product type is its name (each product type's name is unique), so I've tried using conditions in the joined tables, as the Rails guides suggests:

```
Product.joins(:product_type).where(:product_type => {:name => "MyProductTypeUniqueName"})
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
"SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" INNER JOIN \"product_types\" ON \"product_types\".\"id\" = \"products\".\"product_type_id\" WHERE \"product_type\".\"name\" = 'MyProductTypeUniqueName'"
```

Unfortunately it fails with the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product_type"

The error seems to happen because the product_type columns are not included in FROM clause when the SQL is generated ( at least the 'product_type.name' column isn't)

Using PostgreSQL and Rails 3.2.3
SQL results are provided using the `to_sql` method for the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object instance returned

I know that I can make a join directly providing the sql string but this should work as it is an example almost equal to the one in the rails guides.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Both models contains a field called 'name'. Included in case this is the reason the SQL is not building correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
Product.joins(:product_type).where(:table_name => {:name => "MyProductTypeUniqueName"})
```

where :table_name is the name of the table for :product_type in the databse

Comment: Does not work. product_type is a belong_to association, and thus must be in singular

Comment: @RickyAH your table name is not singular, its plural so it has to be :product_types

Comment: The part with the table name was insightful, and I got it working.

I supposed that in the where clause, :product_types referred to the *relation* and not the *table name* (or, more specifically, I though that ActiveRecord would infer the correct table name given the relation). Unfortunately 'product_types' was not the name of the table either (is a table created for a rails engine, so it was really 'refinery_product_types') which adds more confusion.

Please, edit your answer and specify that :product_types must be the name of the TABLE and I'll be glad to accept it.

Thanks @shweta